# Current Amplifier (mA-A)

Tags: amplifier

I'm actually trying to create a solar irradiance meter using a 3V 50mA (max rating) solar cell. The current produce from the solar cell is too small as an input signal for my PIC micro controller 16f873A. I'm using (ACS712) sensitivity of 185mV/A as I-V converter. So basically, im trying to boost the  current (mA) of the solar cell using 2 PNP transistor with 5V DC supply(battery) up to 900mA or more (if possible). My goal is trying to get around (2-3 V) as an output. I've tried using a single transistor and the maximum current i can get is around 100mA. Please help. and Sorry for the silly question earlier.

Comment: You realize that (without an extra power supply) you can only amplify the current if you decrease the voltage by at least the same factor? (Or am I feeding a troll?)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Hanlon's Razor comes to mind. Probably not a troll, just ill-informed.

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram of what you have built so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, "*help by providing a circuit and detail explanation*" is not how this site works.

In any case, the question indicates a possible misunderstanding:

If the intention is to increase available current from a circuit, without introducing additional power sources, then this can only be achieved by reducing the voltage. Power within a system must remain constant - the electrical power, minus the power lost as heat or other forms of energy e.g. sound (speakers) or light (LEDs).

Thus, even assuming a purely hypothetical 100% efficiency, to draw 900 mA from a 3 V, 50 mA source, keeping power constant:

- P<sub>1</sub> = 3 x 0.05 = **150 milliWatt**
- Thus, V<sub>2</sub> = 150 mW / 900 mA = **0.16667 Volts**

Just using 2 transistors will not work, those transistors aren't going to do very well at a 166.7 millivolt operating point.

Hence, the requirement is impractical.

Comment: mW divided by mA gives volts, not mV.

Comment: @DaveTweed Oops, thanks. Corrected it. Net result remains the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using it to amplify my solar cell (3V 50mA).

I suspect that you've misunderstood what an amplifier is.  From the Wikipedia article "[Amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier)":

> An electronic amplifier, amplifier, or (informally) amp is an
>   electronic device that increases the power of a signal. It does this
>   by taking energy from a power supply and controlling the output to
>   match the input signal shape but with a larger amplitude. **In this
>   sense, an amplifier *modulates* the output of the power supply**.

But, your question reads like you've got in mind "amplifying" the output of your power supply (the solar cells) which an amplifier cannot do; the amplifier cannot *create* power.

If your cell produces \$3V \cdot 0.05A = 0.15W\$ of power and you need \$3V \cdot 0.9A = 2.7W\$ of power, no amplifier will provide the missing power.

This is basic physics; energy can be converted from one form to another (always with some loss) but it cannot be created or destroyed.

Now, if what you wish to do is to increase the output *current*, you will necessarily reduce the output *voltage* so that the output power is always strictly less than the input power (remember, there is always some loss).  Thus, you may be able to get \$900mA\$ output current but the price will be a very low output voltage \$V_O \lt 0.167V\$.

Answer (score 0):

An amplifier can amplify 50 mA to 900 mA. But you can't pull the extra 850 mA from thin air. An amplifier not only has an input (your 50 mA) and an output ( the 900 mA), but also a *power supply*, which has to provide the missing 850 mA.

It looks like you don't have that power supply, since the solar cell should be it, and it can't deliver 850 mA.